# Calculate In Duration and Out Duration of Employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I Have a table named `DeviceLogs_8_2016` in which all records of In-time and out-time record of employees are stored.

Table name changes every month.
Ex: The records from `2016-09-01 0:00:00` would be saved in table named `DeviceLogs_9_2016`

Table Contains records of all employees such as below, 
but I need only for a **single UserId on a Specified Date**.

```
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| UserId |       LogDate       | Direction |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 08:21:14 | in        |
|   5012 | 2016-08-08 08:21:26 | out       |
|   7036 | 2016-08-08 08:21:34 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 10:01:14 | in        |
|   8015 | 2016-08-08 10:10:39 | in        |
|   2055 | 2016-08-08 10:11:27 | in        |
|    209 | 2016-08-08 11:28:25 | out       |
|    209 | 2016-08-08 11:32:32 | in        |
|  11253 | 2016-08-08 12:35:17 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 12:37:58 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 13:30:13 | out       |
|   4586 | 2016-08-08 13:30:24 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 13:30:28 | out       |
|    209 | 2016-08-08 13:35:36 | out       |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
```

*Sample Data with only single UserID for the Whole Day is as given Below*

```
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| UserId |       LogDate       | Direction |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 08:20:59 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 08:21:04 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 08:21:14 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 08:21:26 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 08:21:34 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 09:35:26 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 10:01:14 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 12:35:17 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 12:37:58 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 13:29:13 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 13:30:08 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 13:30:13 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 14:30:24 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 17:30:24 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 17:40:24 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 22:15:38 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 22:50:05 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-09 01:20:05 | out       |
|   7034 | 2016-08-09 01:22:10 | in        |
|   7034 | 2016-08-09 04:50:15 | out       |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Considering the Attendance of that day begins from `2016-08-08 05:00:00` and Ends at `2016-08-09 05:00:00`.

I want to calculate the Total In-Duration and Total Out-Duration of the employee on that day. if In or Out appears continuously then we can only consider the last In before Out and  the First Out before In.

I want result to be like

```
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| UserId |  LogDate   | In_Duration | Out_Duration |
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+
|   7034 | 2016-08-08 | 18:12:41    | 02:16:20     |
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I have worked out the calculations in an excel sheet for the specified sample data.

```
╔═════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ row_sno ║ UserId ║       LogDate       ║ Direction ║ In_Diff  ║ Out_Diff ║ Diff_Calculation ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╣
║       1 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 08:20:59 ║ in        ║          ║          ║                  ║
║       2 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 08:21:04 ║ in        ║          ║          ║                  ║
║       3 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 08:21:14 ║ in        ║          ║          ║                  ║
║       4 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 08:21:26 ║ out       ║ 00:00:12 ║          ║ 4th - 3th row    ║
║       5 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 08:21:34 ║ in        ║          ║ 00:00:08 ║ 5th - 4th row    ║
║       6 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 09:35:26 ║ out       ║ 01:13:52 ║          ║ 6th - 5th row    ║
║       7 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 10:01:14 ║ in        ║          ║ 00:25:48 ║ 7th - 6th row    ║
║       8 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 12:35:17 ║ out       ║ 02:34:03 ║          ║ 8th - 7th row    ║
║       9 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 12:37:58 ║ in        ║          ║ 00:02:41 ║ 9th - 8th row    ║
║      10 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 13:29:13 ║ out       ║ 00:51:15 ║          ║ 10th - 9th row   ║
║      11 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 13:30:08 ║ out       ║          ║          ║                  ║
║      12 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 13:30:13 ║ out       ║          ║          ║                  ║
║      13 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 14:30:24 ║ in        ║          ║ 01:01:11 ║ 13th - 10th row  ║
║      14 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 17:30:24 ║ out       ║ 03:00:00 ║          ║ 14th - 13th row  ║
║      15 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 17:40:24 ║ in        ║          ║ 00:10:00 ║ 15th - 14th row  ║
║      16 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 22:15:38 ║ out       ║ 04:35:14 ║          ║ 16th - 15th row  ║
║      17 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-08 22:50:05 ║ in        ║          ║ 00:34:27 ║ 17th - 16th row  ║
║      18 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-09 01:20:05 ║ out       ║ 02:30:00 ║          ║ 18th - 17th row  ║
║      19 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-09 01:22:10 ║ in        ║          ║ 00:02:05 ║ 19th - 18th row  ║
║      20 ║   7034 ║ 2016-08-09 04:50:15 ║ out       ║ 03:28:05 ║          ║ 20th - 19th row  ║
║         ║        ║                     ║           ║          ║          ║                  ║
║         ║        ║                     ║ TOTAL     ║ 18:12:41 ║ 02:16:20 ║                  ║
╚═════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Can you add the row `7034 | 2016-08-09 00:01:14.000 | out` to the table data, and adjust the expected result (if needed)?

Comment: do you have any cases of cross day ? how do you want to handle that ? Also what is the version of `SQL Server` you are using ?

Comment: Yes, cross day cases exists. the shift timings of day starts from 5:00 AM and Ends at 5:00 AM the following day. I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: the expected result that you shown is it a true reflection of the sample data ?

Comment: I have listed a sample data for a single UserId and the manual calculation table.  I have tried to store the IN_swipes and OUT_Swipes in two arrays (in VB script) and tried to get the diference based on the array index number but It dosent help because there are continuous in/out swipes in some cases.

Comment: here's a way of looking at it in SQL, for each IN row for an employee, join all OUT rows for that employee, you then need to select the row where there is NOT EXIST (any record > in time and < out time) as long as you ensure no duplicate IN or OUT time records for that employee (do a prior SELECT DISTINCT in a WITH statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query gives the expected result using `LAG()` function (faster):

```
;with
q0 as (
    SELECT 
        UserId, LogDate, Direction, 
        LAG(Direction) OVER (partition by userid ORDER BY LogDate) AS PreDirection
        -- comment/uncomment below line to calc respectively from the first or the last `[in]` after `[out]`
        -- comment = first, uncomment = last
        , LAG(LogDate) OVER (partition by userid ORDER BY LogDate) AS PreLogDate
    FROM DeviceLogs_8_2016
),
q as (
    select 
        UserId, LogDate, Direction, 
        -- rem/un-rem to calc respectively from the first or the last `[in]` after `[out]`
        /* use this for first */ -- datediff(second, lag(LogDate) over (partition by userid order by logdate), LogDate) secs 
        /* use this for last */ datediff(second, PreLogDate, LogDate) secs
    from q0
    where Direction<>PreDirection or PreDirection is null   
),
s as (
    select *
    from q
    pivot ( SUM(secs) for Direction in ([in], [out])) as p 
)
--/*DEBUG*/ select *, convert(time(0), dateadd(second, secs, 0) ) duration from q order by userid, LogDate
select 
    UserId, 
    convert(time(0), dateadd(second, SUM([out]), 0) ) In_Duration, 
    convert(time(0), dateadd(second, SUM([in]), 0) ) Out_Duration 
from s 
group by userid
```

result:

```
UserId  In_Duration Out_Duration
209     03:17:16    00:33:24
7034    18:12:41    02:15:20
```

Comment: I could not get the expected result....for a different set of data.am I missing something..?

Comment: the only difference is the name of column [Direction], i used [Dir], try to rename it im my `SELECT`. if still does not work, please post the new set of data, I will look into it

Comment: `UserId LogDate Direction
209 2016-08-08 10:10:34.000 in
209 2016-08-08 10:10:39.000 in
209 2016-08-08 10:10:49.000 in
209 2016-08-08 10:10:51.000 in
209 2016-08-08 10:11:27.000 in
209 2016-08-08 11:28:25.000 out
209 2016-08-08 11:32:32.000 in
209 2016-08-08 12:25:15.000 out
209 2016-08-08 12:28:01.000 in
209 2016-08-08 13:35:36.000 out
209 2016-08-08 14:02:07.000 in`

Comment: another set of Sample data is here [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/ehEqww0K)

Comment: 1) pay attention, my solution give `209 03:18:09 00:33:24` not  `209 00:02:26 00:00:05` - 2) in your calc you are missing the last `out-in` period from 13:35:36 to 14:02:07 - 3) if you need to add a "virtual" `out` to close the last `in` we can do something..

Comment: I have given you sample data only for a single day, but my actual table consists the records  of all days in the month of (08). I suppose that may be reason why I get a different result than yours

Comment: Your LAG() solution works good, but there is some variation in data -- please refere this [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/Kj73Fxfe)

Comment: I misunderstood the expected behavior, I was using the 1st `[in]` after the `[out]` and not the last one. I have modified the query to get the desired result. If you like it, please accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (UserId INT, LogDate DATETIME, Direction NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES                             
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 08:20:59', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 08:21:04', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 08:21:14', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 08:21:26', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 08:21:34', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 09:35:26', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 10:01:14', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 12:35:17', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 12:37:58', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 13:29:13', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 13:30:08', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 13:30:13', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 14:30:24', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 17:30:24', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 17:40:24', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 22:15:38', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-08 22:50:05', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-09 01:20:05', 'out'),
(7034 ,'2016-08-09 01:22:10', 'in' ),
(7034 ,'2016-08-09 04:50:15', 'out')


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        UserId ,
        LogDate ,
        Direction,
        LAG(LogDate) OVER (ORDER BY LogDate) AS PreLogDate,
        LAG(Direction) OVER (ORDER BY LogDate) AS PreDirection  
    FROM 
        @Tbl
    WHERE
        UserId = 7034
)

SELECT
    A.UserId ,
    A.LogDate ,
    A.Direction ,
    IIF(In_Diff <> 0, 
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(In_Diff / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((In_Diff / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(In_Diff % 60 AS VARCHAR),2), '')  AS In_Diff ,
    IIF(Out_Diff <> 0,
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(Out_Diff / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((Out_Diff / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(Out_Diff % 60 AS VARCHAR),2), '')  AS Out_Diff
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        CTE.UserId ,
        CTE.LogDate ,
        CTE.Direction ,
        IIF(CTE.Direction = 'out' AND CTE.PreDirection = 'in', DATEDIFF(SECOND, cte.PreLogDate, cte.LogDate), 0) AS In_Diff,
        IIF(CTE.Direction = 'in' AND CTE.PreDirection = 'out', DATEDIFF(SECOND, cte.PreLogDate, cte.LogDate), 0) AS Out_Diff 
    FROM 
        CTE
) A
```

Result

```
UserId  LogDate                     Direction   In_Diff     Out_Diff
7034    2016-08-08 08:20:59.000     in      
7034    2016-08-08 08:21:04.000     in      
7034    2016-08-08 08:21:14.000     in      
7034    2016-08-08 08:21:26.000     out         00:00:12    
7034    2016-08-08 08:21:34.000     in                      00:00:08
7034    2016-08-08 09:35:26.000     out         01:13:52    
7034    2016-08-08 10:01:14.000     in                      00:25:48
7034    2016-08-08 12:35:17.000     out         02:34:03    
7034    2016-08-08 12:37:58.000     in                      00:02:41
7034    2016-08-08 13:29:13.000     out         00:51:15    
7034    2016-08-08 13:30:08.000     out             
7034    2016-08-08 13:30:13.000     out             
7034    2016-08-08 14:30:24.000     in                      01:00:11
7034    2016-08-08 17:30:24.000     out         03:00:00    
7034    2016-08-08 17:40:24.000     in                      00:10:00
7034    2016-08-08 22:15:38.000     out         04:35:14    
7034    2016-08-08 22:50:05.000     in                      00:34:27
7034    2016-08-09 01:20:05.000     out         02:30:00    
7034    2016-08-09 01:22:10.000     in                      00:02:05
7034    2016-08-09 04:50:15.000     out         03:28:05
```

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH 
    Punch_logs_U as (SELECT distinct userid, logdate,direction from punch_logs),
    IN_OUT_TIMES 
    AS (SELECT P1.USERID, 
        P1.LOGDATE, 
        P1.DIRECTION,
        P2.Logdate Logdate_out,
        P2.Direction Direction_out
            FROM Punch_Logs_u P1 
            OUTER APPLY 
            (SELECT TOP 1 PC.Logdate, PC.Direction From Punch_Logs_u PC WHERE 
                                                    PC.UserId = P1.UserId 
                                                    AND 
                                                    PC.Direction = 'OUT'
                                                    AND PC.Logdate >= P1.Logdate) P2
            WHERE P1.Direction = 'IN' AND 
                NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM Punch_Logs_u P3 WHERE 
                                                                P3.UserID = P1.UserId 
                                                            AND P3.direction = 'IN' 
                                                            AND P3.logdate > P1.Logdate
                                                            AND P3.Logdate <= P2.Logdate)
        ) 
        SELECT IO.USERID, 
                IO.Logdate LogDate_in,
                io.Logdate_out, 
                DATEDIFF(minute,io.logdate, io.logdate_out) TimeInMins ,
                DATEDIFF(minute,LAG(logdate, 1,io.logdate) over (partition by userid order by logdate), io.logdate) TimeOUTMins

                    FROM IN_OUT_TIMES IO order by userid, io.logdate
```